# Error RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Tags: networking, virtualbox

On 12.04, running as a guest in VirtualBox using two adapters, I was getting this error in response to `ifup eth1`

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1
```

This was the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host-only interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address         192.168.56.20
        netmask         255.255.255.0
        network         192.168.56.0
        broadcast       192.168.56.255
        gateway         192.168.56.1

# NAT interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

See this question for more about why I configured it this way.
[In VirtualBox, how do I set up host-only virtual machines that can access the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was that two default gateways were being set, one static and one by dhcp. You can't have two default gateways with the same metric.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1043244/comments/8

The solution: remove the gateway line from the configuration of `eth1`.

Or, add an explicit `metric 100` line to `eth1`, to give the `eth1` gateway a lower priority than the `eth2` gateway.

Comment: How to remove the gateway from DHCP complies.