# How to share Guest's internet with host on Virtualbox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, internet, modem

I have a problem that I have been trying to fix over 3 months now, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with Windows 7 as a Guest on VirtualBox, I have a USB Modem which doesn't support Linux, the Modem works good on the Guest but I don't know how to let the Host (Ubuntu) use that connection, I have searched around the Internet and most documents and fixes for how to share Host's connection with Guest, not Guest with Host.
Beside, I've found some posts with similar problem but I couldn't understand the workarounds, I'm still beginner.
So could anyone provide a step-by-step guide how to share Guest's Internet with Host?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: A possible solution could be to set up a proxy or VPN server on your guest and connect to it from your host.

Comment: How I can do that?

Comment: @pcworld Please explain how to do this (Step-by-Step). I have same problem and will appreciate any useful answer

Comment: @pcworld that's a lot easier said than done on a Windows 7 guest.  Not sure that's still a valid approach given that, nor am I sure that's on topic here

Comment: Seems similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69842792/let-host-use-guest-internet-connection

Answer (score 1):

There is a great answer at this post to create a **host only** connection for your Virtualbox that can be seen by Ubuntu to be used for connecting into your VM for network connection sharing.

[In VirtualBox, how do I set up host-only virtual machines that can access the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in)

**Before you follow those directions you need to create the virtual connection.  Copy and paste the following in a terminal window to create it:**

`vboxmanage hostonlyif create`

Also, follow these instructions here after you have created the **host only** connection and have it configured to setup *Internet Connection Sharing* in your Windows VM so that you can share your connection.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

make the network adapter a 'host-only" adapter
( just click devices menu above the running virtual machine
 and change the "attached to" network adapter setting
 to "Host-only" and then you will need to wait a few minutes while
 the changes propagate and/or you change the hosts network
 addresses to match the new guests host-only adapter address (192.168.0.1)