# Ubuntu server terminal doesn't resize screen in VirtualBox

Tags: server, virtualbox, resolution, screen

(Not talking about [resizing the desktop edition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452979/resolution-doesnt-change-when-resizing-virtualbox-window) as most other questions do.)

I've installed [Ubuntu 14.04.1 server 64-bit](http://mirrors.koehn.com/ubuntureleases/14.04.1/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso) in VirtualBox 4.3.10 (not .20, which apparently isn't compatible) but the screen won't grow beyond 80x50 or something like that:

[image]

I've gone through the [steps to install the official guest additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp54932560), which ultimately fail with an X.Org error. Well, duh. I need a server box, without a window manager.

How do I make the terminal match the resolution of the VirtualBox window?

**UPDATE**

I've since installed `virtualbox-guest-utils` and rebooted numerous times. The "Autoresize Guest Display" option is still disabled.

Has nobody else encountered this problem? Or do you just ssh into the box?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

The auto-resize feature is for the X Window System.

From [VirtualBox Manual - 4.2.2.2. Graphics and mouse integration](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idm1948):

> In Linux and Solaris guests, VirtualBox graphics and mouse integration goes through the X Window System. ...After installing the Guest Additions into a fresh installation of a supported Linux distribution..., the guest's graphics mode will change to fit the size of the VirtualBox window on the host when it is resized.

Your best option is probably to SSH into the machine (using PuTTY). In that case, here's a few questions to see next:

- [How to SSH to a VirtualBox guest externally through a host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host)
- [In VirtualBox, how do I set up host-only virtual machines that can access the Internet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293816/in-virtualbox-how-do-i-set-up-host-only-virtual-machines-that-can-access-the-in)
- [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95022/which-type-of-virtualbox-networking-should-i-use)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the guest additions using -

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`

and reboot.

Then, press `host`+`g` to fit the guest in the virtualbox window.

Comment: Tried that, got an error during installation. Updated my post.

Comment: Which version of Virtualbox are you using? 4.3.20?

Comment: Yes. Also `sudo apt-get install dkms` says it's at the newest version. Why is this so complicated :/

Comment: Did you try rebooting? I can see that the Xserver got installed this time.

Comment: I did. The Auto-resize Guest display option is grayed out.

Comment: I would suggest that you downgrade and install Virtualbox 4.3.10 instead. The `virtualbox-guest-utils` package supports 4.3.10 and works perfectly on my system.

Comment: What @RohithMadhavan posts is correct and should be the way to do this. Might be a bug... I have 4.3.10 too and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution [posted here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/how-to-change-font-size-number-of-rows-columns-on-a-terminal) addresses the problem. The solution is to change the terminal window size within the VM machine.