# Virtual Box Ubuntu 16.04 not connecting to internet

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, internet

I have installed VirtualBox 5.2 on Windows 7 host machine and I am attempting to setup up Ubuntu 16.04 in the Virtual Environment.

I have also, update my Network options in Virtualbox to use Bridge Adapter and necessary active Internet port on Windows.

but, I ping to google.com connection doesn't seem to work.

I have tried many solution:

[No internet connection on Virtualbox (Windows 7 as guest, ubuntu 13.04 as host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host)

[VirtualBox no Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728269/virtualbox-no-internet-connection)

Comment: Do you have other virtual machines? Do they have access to internet? Might be a windows problem.

Comment: No I don't have any other VM running or VM software. This is the single VM I am trying to setup.

Comment: Please refer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/293816/810348), it may help you in setting up networking in the virtual machine