# Samba file server access from windows

Tags: 22.04, samba

I have a Samba share folder in my Virtualbox Ubuntu server.
Is it possible to access that shared folder from Windows?
If yes, I can't connect to the shared folder in Windows how I debug for the problem?
I  used [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview) to set up my Ubuntu server in Vbox.
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: its the lastest ubuntu server on the website

Comment: i mean LTS version

Comment: How is your network configured in VirtualBox? It must be set to promiscuous mode and to allow traffic from all network locations, otherwise it will be filtered by the host system.

Comment: This mainly works if you use "bridge" network in Virtualbox.

Comment: yes but when i use bridge mode ill lost my connection to internet

Comment: if you can not access the virtualbox node via network in any way, you can not access a samba share (or any other type)

Comment: This is not a Samba issue but a Virtual Box network setup issue. How to do this has already been answered in posts such as this: https://askubuntu.com/q/293816/134479